# Connecting a tablet to a pc as a mouse

Tags: tablet, touchscreen

I was wondering how I would go about a certain problem.

I want to connect my tablet touchscreen to my pc to use the touchscreen as the mouse for the pc.

I want to do this because I want to Digitally draw on a program on my desktop pc, but as I am very bad with a mouse for drawing, I wanted to draw using a touchscreen pen and my tablet, and have it draw on the PC. I apologise for not saying this before, but I forgot to say it is a windows tablet, so android apps will not work on the device.

Comment: As I am engaged to an artist, I have to ask: are you planning on trying to get pressure sensitivity with your drawing strokes, or do you simply want the tablet touchscreen to "work" for making plain lines without pressure sensitivity and the things that artists want in their  drawings?  Getting the tablet pen/screen to work as a mouse is one thing - getting it to be a replacement for an actual drawing tablet device is another

Comment: I am attempting to be able to just draw on the mouse. Pressure sensitivity is not required in this instance, but I would like to be able to use the touchscreen stylus just to touch the screen, and have it draw those lines on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a quick Google search, I found a how to guide on the matter. Although it uses Android, I'm sure it would work in a similar way with Apple :)

[Link](http://www.howtogeek.com/161602/how-to-use-your-android-device-as-a-mouse-keyboard-joystick-and-more/)

EDIT: Here's a link for a guide with an iPad :)

[iPad](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-augment-your-computer-with-an-ipad-513479575)

Comment: External links can break or be unavailable, in which case your answer would not be useful.  Please include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  With a little more rep, you will be able to post helpful links in a comment.  Thanks.